# Kleisli is initial, a coherence issue

Tags: ct.category-theory

Usually, when proving that the Kleisli adjunction of a monad $M$ is initial in the category of all adjunctions splitting the monad, we hide coherences under the carpet.
Or so did I, until I got stubborn and tried to prove the result "for real" (and feed it to a proof assistant, so even realer).

Let's define a category as follows: fix a monad $M$ on a category $\cal C$ and define $Split(M)$;

- an object in $Split(M)$ is an adjunction $(F\dashv G)$ such that the induced monad is $M$; in agda pseudocode,

  ```
  -- the category of adjunctions splitting a given monad
  record SplitObj : Set _ where
  field
    D   : Category
    F   : Functor C D
    G   : Functor D C
    adj : F ⊣ G -- the type of this is "adjunction": a record containing 
                -- unit, counit, zigzag identities
    GF≃M : G ∘F F ≃ M.F -- the type of this is "natural isomorphism 
                        -- of functors", defined elsewhere
    -- now call `beta` the isomorphism in the last field: we must require
    η-eq : ∀ {A} → β _ ∘ η A ≈ unit _
    μ-eq : ∀ {A} → β _ ∘ μ A ≈ G (counit (F A)) ∘ β _ ∘ M (β A)
  ```
- A morphism between $(F\dashv G)$ and $F'\dashv G')$ is a functor $H$ compatible with all I defined above:

  ```
  record Split⇒ (X Y : SplitObj) : Set _ where
  field
    H     : Functor D D'
    HF≃F' : H ∘ F ≃ F'
  -- G'H≃G : G' ∘ H ≃ G this field is redundant, strictly speaking...
  ```

Clearly, I *have* to take into account these maps $\beta$ and $\gamma : HF\cong F'$, and agda is quite unforgiving about their presence in each and every proof. Evidently, this poses many coherence problems here and there, and even though it's practically evident how to define a unique functor $(F_T\dashv G_T)\to (L\dashv R)$ that is a morphism in the above sense, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ get in the way *a lot*. So much that I got stuck into a point where I suspect I have to *require* that the commutativity I need is, indeed, true.

Long story made very short, I have this diagram, witnessing the fact that there is a unique morphism, up to isomorphism, from the Kleisli adjunction to any other adjunction $L\dashv R$: such an isomorphism in $Split(M)$ must be a natural transformation, and there is a canonical choice for this, taking the isomorphisms specified in $L\dashv R$.

Point is, I don't know how to conclude that it commutes:

[image]

More precisely, the part I have no clue why it commutes i the one enclosed by the red arrow: something very weird is happening there, mixing the counit of $(F_T\dashv U_T)$, that there is called $F\dashv G$, and the counit of $(L\dashv R)$; the red arrow itself is something peculiar, because it compares the monad $GF$ and the monad $RL$ (they are, of course, isomorphic, because they are both isomorphic to $M$).

The subdiagrams marked with "NAT" commute by naturality. The "OK" triangle is commutative because the red arrow is defined to make it such. What about the rest?...

Comment: Some small questions: 1- in your agda pseudocode for Split(M), the type of the 5th line should be "isomorphism of *monads*", right ? 2- The "redundant" bit in your definition of the morphisms in Split(M) seems like it might actually very much cause trouble; it should either not be there, *or* come with an extra morphism that indicates the compatibility of this isomorphism with the previous one - how did you deal with this ? (2- is my more serious question; in fact if your definition of morphisms in Split(M) is as is, then the statement is simply not true)

Comment: (note that your missing square seems to involve both gamma and beta, so it is reasonable to expect that you need some compatibility between them for the square to commute; and indeed, it is needed for the statement to hold)

Comment: 1- yes, indeed. 2- it is indeed commented out. As for a compatibility between $\gamma$ and $\beta$, yes, I think it must be required. But in what form, and motivated by what conceptual reason? (A more precise question: should I require the missing commutativity as is, or a more general, and more intuitive to justify, compatibility condition?)

Comment: So the diagram you are considering is your trying to show that $\gamma$ is natural ?

Comment: Heh, not exactly... naturality of $\gamma$ is part of the axioms. I end up with that condition starting from a bigger diagram, in the proof that there is only one functor $! : Kl(T)\to \cal D$ that one defines given the Kleisli adjunction and a generic object of Split(M). I defined the functor and showed that it is a morphism in Split(M) --an unfathomable pain. Now I'm proving that any other morphism $Kl(T)\to \cal D$ is isomorphic -in Split(M)- to bang.

Comment: Point is, the record I have to fill wants some data that are basically filled automatically by the isomorphisms $\beta,\gamma$ filling the triangles for $(L\dashv R)$. The fact that these are invertible is part of the record saying they are natural isomorphisms, of course. But the proof that they are natural is now hindered by the way $!$ is defined on morphisms, using $\beta,\gamma$. So one definitely needs something more, but what?

Comment: So: if you say that there is no reasonable way to get out of this mess, the most sensible way might be strictify the definition, and motivate the brutal strictification with this thread linked in the PR to Jacques :P

Comment: Surely the morphism $H$ from $F \dashv G$ to $F' \dashv G'$ needs to respect the existing equivalences to $M$ as well, a condition not present in your Agda code? That is, there is an endomorphism on $M$ given by $M \cong GF \cong G' H F \cong G' F' \cong M$, and I would expect we would have to demand this endomorphism be identity.

Comment: Good point, yes.

Comment: I would also expect the morphism $H$ to have to be demanded to respect the actual adjunction structure. $H$ automatically respects the units of the adjunctions once it respects the identification with the monad, in that these are determined by the unit of the monad, but there's still more structure to the adjunctions not fully determined by the monad (as in, the co-units).

Comment: That is, we have two maps from $F' G$ to $H$, given by the identification of $F' G$ with either $H F G$ or $F' G' H$ and then applying the corresponding adjunction co-unit. I would expect we would have to demand that these two maps be equal.

Comment: I agree with you, and these isomorphisms are all reasonable. But this begs the question of what they exactly are: I have never seen/heard such a coherence result (and I have highly inadequate knowledge to navigate them and use them properly...).

Comment: Oh, I'm actually wrong on the last point: $H$ respecting the adjunction unit automatically ensures that it respects the full adjunction structure including the co-unit (Exercise 4.2.v from Riehl's "Category Theory in Context"; see also Proposition 5.2.12).

Comment: Ok, so I tried to write down a proof to see where your diagram came in, and I spotted it. First, as is clear from what you drew, one can completely remove the $X$ - this makes things a little simpler because then every map is a map of functors. Second, I think what's happening is all hidden in the compatibility between the isomorphism $HF\cong L$ and the monad isomorphism $M= GF\cong RL$. Namely, the isomophism $HF\cong L$ already induces a map $G\to RH$, and together, these induce a map $M=GF\to RHF\cong RL$, and you must require this to be the monad isomorphism.

Comment: Spelling out the "this induces a map $G\to RH$" in terms of units and counits will give you things that look like your diagram, and if I'm not mistaken, are enough to conclude. In other words, I agree with Sridhar's first comment.

Comment: Aha, I see! Yes, I was fiddling with the mate of $HF\cong L$ to see where it leads asking something to that. This might be the way out. Pray to the agda gods for me :P (Certainly, $G\to RH$ need not be invertible, am I right?)

Comment: In general, $G\to RH$ has no reason to be invertible, *but* in this situation it is : indeed, $F$ is essentially surjective, so $GF\to RHF$ being invertible is enough to ensure that $G\to RH$ is. I have the diagrams written down on a sheet of paper, but diagrams are a bit of a pain on MO so if you figure it out, I'll let you answer the question :D

Comment: After a moment of reflection it's what I thought, yes.